# A difficulty in understanding an example of a remark on pointwise convergence of Fourier series.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, pointwise-convergence

The theorem and the remark and an example on a remark are given below:

[image]

But I do not understand the example $f(x) = x$, specifically I do not understand:

1- what do the author mean by "$f(x) = x$ as a function in $PC(2\pi)$" and why this function has a discontinuity at $ x = (2k -1)\pi$, for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}.$

2- I also do not understand why this function is only piecewise differentiable in $(-\pi , \pi)$ and not differentiable? (by theway I know that differentiability implies piecewise differentiable ...... am I correct? )

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f(x)=x$ is not piecewise continuous, but if we define another function $g(x) = f(x)$ for $|x|< \pi$ and define $g$ so that it is $2 \pi$ periodic then we have a function that is equal to $f$ for $|x| < \pi$ and $g \in PC(2 \pi)$.

I have not defined $g$ at odd multiples of $\pi$, but there is no need to here as the Fourier series are 'insensitive' to changes on a set of measure zero.

The function $g$ is smooth (not just differentiable) in $(\pi,\pi)$, hence for
$x \in (\pi,\pi)$ we have ${1 \over 2}( \lim_{t \uparrow x} g(t) + \lim_{t \downarrow x} g(t))
 = g(x) = x$ and so the Fourier series of $g$ converges (pointwise) to the value $x$.

You can see that, similarly & unsurprisingly, the Fourier series converges to $0$ at odd
multiples of $\pi$ (because $g$ is odd for $|x| < \pi$).

Note that for $|x| < \pi$ the convergence is **not** absolute.

Look at the excellent answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95155/27978 for more detail about the convergence.

Comment: is not every continuous function piecewise continuous?

Comment: sorry I can not understand your answer at all ...... could you please make it simpler and to the point related to my questions? thank you.

Comment: Yes, a continuous (differentiable) function is piecewise continuous (differentiable). The function $f$ is smooth (continuous, differentiable, etc) everywhere, but is not in $PC(2 \pi)$. The function $g \in PC(2 \pi)$ that matches $f$ everywhere except (necessarily) at $\pm \pi$ is only piecewise continuous (differentiable).

Comment: Perhaps you could be more specific about what is hard to follow and I will try to elaborate.

Comment: what is the difference between the function $f(x) = x , x \in \mathbb{R}$ and the function $f(x) = x$  in $PC(2\pi)$? is the latter the circle?

Comment: Suppose $f(x) = x$ everywhere. Also note that any function in $PC(2 \pi)$ is $2 \pi $ periodic. If we choose $g \in PC(2 \pi)$ such that $f(x) = g(x)$ for $|x| < \pi$, then it is clear that $f(x) = g(x)$ for $|x| < \pi$. However, since $g(x+2 \pi) = g(x)$ it is clearly a different unction than $f$. It might help to sketch $f,g$.

Comment: Note that the Fourier series only needs the underlying function to be defined for $|x| < \pi$, so it is a convenience to take the underlying function as $2 \pi $ periodic so that we can talk about limits, etc, without having to deal with cases where $x$ crosses the $|x|=\pi$ boundary.

Comment: is the latter a circle?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. You can think of Fourier series as a representation of functions defined on the circle, but I am not sure that is what you are asking.

Comment: why $f(x) = x$ is not continuous at odd multiples of $\pi$  .... I think I have stated my questions clearly ...... either in comments or in the main question ......sorry if I said this but your answers are not to the point.

Comment: What is the shape of the two functions graphically?

Comment: ??? Draw the function $f(x) = x$ and the function $g$ which is the same as $f$ or $|x| < \pi$ and then periodic.

Comment: I think $f(x) = x $ with $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is piecewise continuous but it is not periodic ...... am I correct?

Comment: It is smooth everywhere.

Comment: And not periodic.